# myPHP Admin Linking Table / Columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I've been looking at this all day and there doesn't seem to be an online source that does what I need. I want to set the value of `Total_Price = Product_TCost + Shipping_TCost`. Online sources only give me the option of selecting them and making a new table, but it does not dynamically change with the information. I want to just enter the `Product_TCost` and `Shipping_TCost` and have `Total_Price` automatically insert the value - just how `TIMESTAMP` works.

---

I am having some trouble trying to do a Computed Column Specification using phpMyAdmin. I am used to SQL using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studios.

- When I try to insert `([Product_Total]+[Shipping_Total])` in my
  `Total_Price` column, I get an error.
- My `Product_TCost` column in `Invoice` table should be `([SmallBox_Total]*9.99 + ([LargeBox_Total]*14.99)`
- My `Shipping_TCost` column in `Invoice` table should be `([SmallBox_Total]*0.99 + ([LargeBox_Total]*1.99)`
- Same goes with trying to auto populate `ID_Order` with
  `Shipping_Company` in my `Invoice` table.

  I had it all working in SQL management Studios, but phpMyAdmin has a completely different user interface. I didn't use the SQL commands too much, I did everything with the `Column Properties` from Microsoft SQL Studios.

[This is the column properties I used in Microsoft SQL Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJtL7.png)

[This is my database and where I can't get the linking done correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMeNS.png)

Basically what I am doing and ultimately failing - using phpMyAdmin - is this:

1. When I enter an `ID_Order` into the `Invoice` table, it should pull the `SmallBox_Total`, `LargeBox_Total`, and auto-calculate the `Product_TCost`, `Shipping_TCost` and `Total_Price`
2. When `ID_Order` is entered, the `Shipping_Company` should automatically be pulled as well
3. The only thing not being pulled is the `MCT_Code`, which will be entered by the user.

I had this working beautifully in Microsoft SQL Studios, but transferring it over to a foreign system (to me) has completely stopped my progress.

Comment: They are differing technologies. It might be worth your time to read up on the MySQL documentation, and do some basic web searching for differences between the technology you know and the new one. It will pay off in the long run for you to understand the SQL command style and syntax, and how it is implemented in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, my main problem with this is that I don't know what to even look up. I don't have the time to learn an entirely different technology, just how to transfer the information over from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a trigger. You can create a trigger that will do both of these things; it basically gets attached to the INSERT on `ID_Order` and runs whatever commands you want including automatically calculating values to insert in other columns.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html